# My Python Code failed to saved multiple stream of data to storage file

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

### Problem Definition

Create your own command-line address-book program using which you can browse, add, modify, delete or search for your contacts such as friends, family and colleagues and their information such as email address and/or phone number. Details must be stored for later retrieval.

Based on the above problem description I was able to developed the below program,

**The challenged I am currently facing is that;**
1. Only one contact is saved to the local storage, old contact is always overwritten. I want every instance of the object to save different contact to same file (phonelist)
2. contact_del method through error though it does what it supposed to do, can someone tell me what is wrong with that section of the code and why do I get the error.Finally I want that error to be suppress.

```
import pickle
#   Declare the Class
class phone_book:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize The Phone Book"""
        print('This is a command Line phone Book Directory')


    def add_detail(self):
        """ Detail of our Contacts is being collected"""
        address_book = {}
        address_value = []

        #   Accepting Value from the User
        print('Let add our friends Details')
        address_name = input('Enter name : ')
        address_phone = int(input('Enter phone Number : '))
        address_email = input('enter email : ')
        addess_Gtype = input('Specify Contact Group Type : ')
        address_value.append(address_phone)
        address_value.append(address_email)
        address_value.append(addess_Gtype)

        for i in address_value:
            address_book[address_name] = address_value
            #   Sending our Data to Permanent Storage
            with open("phonelist.txt", "wb") as myFile:
                pickle._dump(address_book, myFile)

    # Declare Function that will enable us to modify the data enter
    @classmethod
    def detail_modify(cls):
        """ We are Modifying our old friends Details"""
        modify_contact = input('Enter the Name of the to modify : ')
        with open("phonelist.txt", "rb") as myFile:
            address_book = pickle._load(myFile)
            # Iterate over the supply name
            for name, name_detail in address_book.items():
                if modify_contact not in name:
                    print('The contact does not exist')
                else:
                    print('We are ready to modify  Mr :', name)
                    address_phone = int(input('Enter phone Number : '))
                    address_email = input('enter email : ')
                    addess_Gtype = input('Specify Contact Group Type : ')
                    name_detail[0] = address_phone
                    name_detail[1] = address_email
                    name_detail[2] = addess_Gtype

                    # Finally we updating the Details enter
                    for i in name_detail:
                        address_book[name] = name_detail
                        #   Sending our Data to Permanent Storage
                        with open("phonelist.txt", "wb") as myFile:
                            pickle._dump(address_book, myFile)

    # Declare a function that Search for Keywords in the directory
    @classmethod
    def phone_search(cls):
        """ Return Contact Details based on the Keyword Enter"""
        keyword = input('Enter word you are searching for : ')
        with open("phonelist.txt", "rb") as myFile:
            address_book = pickle._load(myFile)


        #   Iteration over the received data from the storage
        for name, name_detail in address_book.items():
            if keyword in name or name_detail:
                print(address_book)

            else:
                print("Keyword not Found")

    # Were are removing people we are no more in friendship with
    @classmethod
    def contact_del(cls):
        """ We are deleting Contact we are done with friendship"""
        with open("phonelist.txt", "rb") as myFile:
            address_book = pickle._load(myFile)
        contact_remove = input('Enter name of Contact to Removed : ')
        for name, name_detail in address_book.items():
            if contact_remove == name:
                del address_book[contact_remove]
                print(contact_remove, 'Successfully removed')
            # Updating Our Storage again
            with open("phonelist.txt", "wb") as myFile:
                pickle._dump(address_book, myFile)
            else:
                print('Name Supply is not valid')

    # Sending the number of Phone contact to output Screen
    @classmethod
    def contact_view(cls):
        """ Displaying Our contacts Details"""
        with open("phonelist.txt", "rb") as myFile:
            address_book = pickle._load(myFile)
        print(address_book, 'Number of Contacts ',  len(address_book))

# Running below instance of object only retain last object the first
phone_book.contact_view()
contact1 = phone_book()
contact1.add_detail()
contact2 = phone_book()
contact2.add_detail()
phone_book.contact_view()
phone_book.phone_search()
phone_book.contact_del()
```

*Despite the error above the called method(phone_book.contact_del()) removed the intended User, See the output  of phone_book.contact_del() below*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> old contact is always overwritten.

You are opening your files in 'write' mode, which will overwrite any file that has the same name.  You need to use 'append' mode.  Change `open("phonelist.txt", "wb")` to `open("phonelist.txt", "ab")` See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), specifically the part about the `mode` argument.

> contact_del method through error though it does what it supposed to do

The problem is here:

```
for name, name_detail in address_book.items():
    if contact_remove == name:
        del address_book[contact_remove]  # Don't do this
```

You are modifying a dictionary while iterating over the values in it, which results in `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.  In general, do not change a dictionary (or list!) while you are inside a for-loop.  Modifying data structures inside loops that iterate over them can lead to unexpected bugs.

In your case a simple if-statement will suffice:

```
# Check if the requested contact is in the address book
if contact_remove in address_book:
    del address_book[contact_remove]
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick responses, I had updated the code(my code now use mode="ab") to reflect your response, but the data is not write to the disk. I am on window10 and running python3.4 (64bit). is there anything I need to change in the code aside the mode.Thanks in advance